# Unable to connect through SQLPLUS from a oracle client 11g to 18c database

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

There are a few topics on web about connecting issue from 11g to 18c, sqlplus vs sqldeveloper and etc, but not a combination of all.  Here's the question:

I'm trying to connect to a 18c Oracle database via sqlplus (11g 32-bit client) from my PC.  All of the below works:

```
1) connect via Mobaxterm (as oracle) from my PC that has 18.0.0.0 client  
2) connect via sqldeveloper, with both SID / service name option tested  
3) TNSPING from my PC to the 18c DB (i.e. tnsname.ora is good)  
4) sqlplus works from my PC to another 11g oracle DBs
```

Only thing that does not works is the combination of sqlplus from 11g 32bit client to 18c database.  The error is

```
invalid username/password; logon denied.
```

Same credential is used throughout the testing (which worked on 1) and 2) above).  I made sure:

```
A) These are added to the sqlnet.ora:  
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11  
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=11  

B) Oracle_SID is pointing to the correct name

C) sqlplus is run from CMD as administrator
```

Please let me know if i should provide more info.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need 11g client?

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks Chris but the 12g client i had have other issue connecting to some other 11g DB, so I guess 11g is the only option for now

Comment: What issues?  Maybe they are simpler to resolve.  Can't you use multiple Instant Clients and set PATH (in a .bat script or some other way) before you invoke the tool that depends on a particular version?  If you explained more about all the problems you are trying solve (or tools you are trying to use), I could give more detailed advice

Comment: @ChristopherJones ended up using a different computer with 12g client available as I do not have the privilege to change the Env variables on my PC.

Comment: Are you aware that passwords are now case sensitive by default in 18/19 databases?  So of the other ways you are connecting may be handling this behind the scenes, but I would ensure that your password was all upper or all lower and test this (can be reset to a decent password later)

Comment: @ShaunPeterson Thanks Shaun, I had made sure to exclude case sensitive being a possible issue with all UPPER case and also all lower case ID / password.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact version number of your Oracle client version 11, that client is possibly not compatible with the Oracle server version 18c.

As I have no access to the support pages of Oracle myself, I can only provide this link with a [detailed compatibility matrix](https://oraclefact.wordpress.com/2018/04/05/client-server-interoperability-support-matrix-for-different-oracle-versions-doc-id-207303-1/).